# very slow input from bluetooth barcode scanner to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, barcode

I have an issue where a barcode is taking nearly a second per character to write to an edit text, a quick bit of background.

I use the same code throughout my application and in every other instance the barcode takes milliseconds to output the string.

I cannot work out why it is so slow in this instance. It reads character by character looking for keyCode 66, the end of the barcode.

Here is the code I am using, this is contained from within a fragment.

```
  txtBarcode = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        txtBarcode.requestFocus();
        txtBarcode.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (keyCode == 66 ) {
                        String chars = txtBarcode.getText().toString();
                        if (chars.length() > 1) bcode = chars.trim();

                        if (bcode.length() > 0) {
                            pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Checking - Please Wait...", false);
                            new updateScanned(getActivity(), DeliveryScanFragment.this, bcode, CourierHeaderID).execute();
                            bcode = "";
                            txtBarcode.setText("");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
            return false;
            }
        });
```

and the xml file for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/tvdc"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/iteminstructions"
                android:id="@+id/tvinstructions"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvdc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/expecteditems"
                android:id="@+id/tvexp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvinstructions"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvinstructions"
                android:layout_marginRight="115dp"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/scanneditems"
                android:id="@+id/tvscan"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvexp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvinstructions"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cartonimage"
                android:src="@drawable/p"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tvinstructions"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tvdc"
                android:contentDescription="Carton Image"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/altcode"
                    android:id="@+id/altcode"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/colour"
                    android:id="@+id/colour"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/size"
                    android:id="@+id/size"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/expecteditems"
                    android:id="@+id/expected"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">


            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/altcode"
                    android:id="@+id/altcode0"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/colour"
                    android:id="@+id/colour0"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/size"
                    android:id="@+id/size0"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/scanneditems"
                    android:id="@+id/scanned"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:id="@+id/LVExpected"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
                android:background="#ffdfffdb"/>

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:id="@+id/LVScanned"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="#ffc2ffff"/>
    </TableRow>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/processdel"
                android:id="@+id/btnProcess"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="34dp"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/clearButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
                android:src="@drawable/clearhistorys"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnProcess"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnProcess"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etInput"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clearButton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:minWidth="60dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

I can only guess that something in my xml is causing the delay, however this is a total guess and may not be relevant, my logcat output for reading the barcode is as follows:

```
01-20 13:01:43.531  22402-22408/com.x.retailtabs.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 799K, 31% free 6497K/9364K, paused 24ms+5ms, total 58ms
01-20 13:01:43.867  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:43.875  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:44.796  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:44.804  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:45.648  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:45.656  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:46.531  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:46.539  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:47.367  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:47.375  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:48.250  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:48.257  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:49.156  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:49.156  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:50.015  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:50.015  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:50.101  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress = 0
01-20 13:01:50.101  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
01-20 13:01:50.101  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
01-20 13:01:50.359  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app E/ViewRootImpl﹕ onInputEvent:dispatchAttachedToWindow is not called.[event:KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=403650276, downTime=403650263, deviceId=18, displayId=0, source=0x101 }]
01-20 13:01:51.211  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:51.211  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:51.336  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
01-20 13:01:51.336  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
01-20 13:01:51.336  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
01-20 13:01:51.343  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
01-20 13:01:51.359  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:51.382  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:51.398  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:51.429  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress = 0
01-20 13:01:51.429  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
01-20 13:01:51.429  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
01-20 13:01:51.757  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
01-20 13:01:51.757  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
01-20 13:01:51.757  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
01-20 13:01:51.757  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
01-20 13:01:51.796  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-20 13:01:52.937  22402-22408/com.x.retailtabs.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 217K, 29% free 6668K/9364K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 45ms
01-20 13:01:53.461  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:53.711  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:53.898  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:53.921  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:53.937  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
01-20 13:01:53.961  22402-22402/com.x.retailtabs.app E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you end up with a solution?

Comment: Not really, Using the exact same code on Lollipop the scan was near enough instant, I can only assume that it is something between touchwiz and the input. When the device was not connected and debugging it was quicker, quick enough for the purpose it was used for, but no where near as quick as lollipop?!

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, I used setOnEditorActionListener() as this resolved it, why I do not know!